# How can I have Hashable element type for an Array that is wrapped value for optional

Tags: swift

I am looking the correct syntax of this code:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Array<Element> where Element == Hashable {

}
```

The elements of Array are Hashable.

Comment: What does that mean? Are you saying that you need a function that will return an `Optional` or an "array of hashable elements" (`ArrayList<Hashable>`)?

Comment: I did not mention function.

Comment: Never mind. I didn't see the tag before posting my comment.

Comment: You can’t specify this generic constraint at the level of the extension, you have to instead express it on the function within. What are you trying to call in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either constrain every member, or use a typealias. But you can't use properties unless you use the typealias solution.

```swift
typealias OptionalHashableArray<Hashable: Swift.Hashable> = [Hashable]?

extension OptionalHashableArray {
  var : String { "" }
}

([] as Optional).
```

```swift
extension Optional {
  func <Hashable: Swift.Hashable>() -> String
  where Wrapped == [Hashable] {
    ""
  }
}

[AnyHashable]?.none.()
```